# How do I play this? Beginner Technique

Tags: technique, sheet-music, keyboard, beginner

Hi I'm sorry in advance for my lack of terminally as I am just beginning to teach myself to play the keyboard. In this piece of music how would you play the treble note in the first staff that has "C" over it? I don't think it is a chord and it is different from other treble and bass clef notes that I've seen so I can't figure it out. Basically any place where the notes are "double staked" on the same clef I can't figure out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://www.sheetmusicdirect.com/se/ID_No/57741/Product.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The **C** is called a Pop Chord Symbol; this means that you are playing a C major chord.

I assume you are talking about the first C on the chart. You will play this first ***chord*** by:

**Right Hand**

Placing your thumb on E and your middle finger on G (do this above the middle C on your keyboard)

**Left Hand**

Place your thumb on C -- ( the one below middle C)

When you see notes stacked on each other, it means to play the notes all at once.

When notes are all played simultaneously, this is called a harmony.

If this doesn't make sense, consider picking up a beginner piano book or lessons if you can afford it.

I am currently working on [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0882848186) and it will help you a lot I think.

I'd also look up a YouTube video explaining time signature and quarter notes and stuff like that if you are not familiar with that.

P.S. In this chart you will also see things like G/B. This means that you are playing a G major chord with a B as the bass note.

Comment: Your way of playing that first chord is hard! Better would be thumb on E and middle finger on G.

Comment: @Tim I was going off what the sheet music said for fingering. If you look at his link this is the fingering implied by the numbers above the notes

Comment: @Tim They do this because the bass line descends from C

Comment: I still don't get it. The quoted way has r.h. thumb under the hand to play G, and middle finger over to play E. Most people would play the other way round. And the bass line should be separate, with no reference to r.h. fingers.

Comment: @tim just re read my answer, i updated it. I meant more middle finger and pinky

Comment: I'd still not go that way, as there is an A note to play, and for a beginner, stretching pinky from G to A isn't necessary. Always try to put the hand where it can cover the next few notes comfortably.

Comment: @tim I think he will have to crossover no matter what with that first am in the chart. Hmm this is a bad chart for a beginner

Comment: Not so much of a crossover, as gently moving the whole hand to a higher position. It's not too bad a chart.

Comment: @Tim k updated it again.

Answer (score 1):

I would play exactly the notes that are written, which are a perfectly adequate "easy" version of the song.   The chord symbols are for a guitarist who wants to strum along, or for a more advanced keyboardist who might want to elaborate.   They are also useful for those "home keyboards" where you get an auto-accompaniment by holding down a chord in the LH.